# JPA Named query gives Error as The right expression is not a valid expression and The query contains a malformed ending

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have the **Named query** as below and passing dynamic parameter

```
  select count(table1) from Table1 table1 where table1.nameId in 
  (select table2.nameId from Table2 table2 where table2.hicNumber =:value0) 
  and table1.indicator = :value1 
  and table1.startDate = :value2 
  and NVL(table1.endDate,'31-DEC-2999')=NVL(:value3,'31-DEC-2999')
```

It gives Error as

```
[235, 255] The right expression is not a valid expression.
[256, 297] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

Can you please help me for what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Apart from the fact that NVL is not valid JPQL, as the JPA spec would tell ?

Comment: @DN1 Not getting?

Comment: Read the jpa spec and it will tell you that there is no function nvl in the jpql query language. Jpql != Sql, as has been said on here endless times

Comment: @DN1 thanks i got it.. and replaced by `COALESCE`.